# How i Can Draw a bottom cord in circle?

Tags: css

[image]

this is the image, I want to draw something same like this but I am not able to draw the cord part.

Comment: the existing code please

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/wmr5agmu/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that structure by using below code...
also check [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wmr5agmu/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle">
  <div>
    Best leads and exposure to your
    institution with professional photography services.<br>
    Explore more
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:solid 2px #cd9933;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#fff;
  position: relative;
  margin:0px auto;
}
.circle div{
  background:#cd9933;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  text-align:center;
  height:39%;
  width:100%;
  color:#fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through a gradient background, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/of9nv1k0/1/

```
<div id="circle"></div>

#circle{
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 60%, #eaa320 60%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 60%,#eaa320 60%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 60%,#eaa320 60%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaa320',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Results in a circle with the top part white, bottom part orange.